# Sending messages to Azure IoT Hub from within Windows docker container

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-iot-hub

I am pretty new to Docker and I have to build a container that can run a Python script that sends messages periodically to an Azure IoT Hub using the rows of a CSV file. I have already built this container using Linux, but due to limitations of my resources, I must rebuild the image using a Windows container. This is the setup of my Dockerfile that I am attempting to use:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809

# Install pip requirements
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app 
ADD SimulatedDeviceFitbit.py .

WORKDIR /app 
COPY sensor_original2.csv .

CMD ["python", "SimulatedDeviceFitbit.py"]
```

The only package added using Pip is the azure-iot-device library. The CSV is used to read the data that will be sent as a message and the script handles the sending of the message. Whenever I run the image, the error:

`azure.iot.device.common.transport_exceptions.TlsExchangeAuthError: TlsExchangeAuthError(None) caused by SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')`

The connection made to the IoT hub in the script looks like this:

`client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)`

I checked my network devices through Docker and did not see any issues but obviously I am missing something. I have no experience networking in a container and would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your container image is missing Baltimore Root CA.

As you are using a [Windows Server Core Container Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore) you will probably need to enable some WindowsFeatures in order to import the certificate to the certificate store using [certutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil).

Your DockerFile should include something like this:

```
# Copy PFX file (located on HOST on C:\test) to container and install
ADD "c:\test\BaltimoreRootCA.pfx" "c:\test\BaltimoreRootCA.pfx"
RUN certutil -importpfx "c:\test\BaltimoreRootCA.pfx"
```

You can export Baltimore Root CA from a windows machine or copy it from [Azure IoT SDK C Github Repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/certs/certs.c)

- As a reference check also this repo with some steps on how to enable windows features and import certificates: https://github.com/fabioharams/container
- And alternative ways to import certs on this related SO thread: [Docker SSL Cert for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041648/docker-ssl-cert-for-windows)