# docker push with Docker Desktop on WSL2 doesn't trust private CA

Tags: docker, wsl-2, docker-desktop, certificate-authority

From Ubuntu running in WSL2, I'm attempting to push a docker image to a private docker registry. It fails with the following error:

```
Get "https://docker.example.com/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I'm using Docker Desktop with the WSL2 integration enabled.

Where do I install the root CA certificate so that docker can find it? I've tried the following:

- Installing it in the Trusted Root Certification Authority store in Windows and restarting Docker Desktop Service.
- Installing it in the Ubuntu CA store.

Neither of these works.

Answer (score 2):

The CA certificate should be placed in the directory `C:\ProgramData\docker\certs.d\`. Then restart the docker service with `restart-service docker` from an admin powershell.

Comment: This answer -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57137051/8446 -- says that's no longer needed and says to put it in the root CA store (which I tried).